org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Cannot set field 'nameAlternativeTitle' to instantiate 'com.espacogeek.geek.models.MediaModel'
On requestedFields I received flowing map:
[
  "nameAlternativeTitle",
  "nameMedia",
  "idMedia",
  "aboutMedia",
  "alternativeTitle": [
    "nameAlternativeTitle",
  ],
]

MediaModel class doesn't have nameAlternativeTitle, so isJoinableField() and isValidField() will return false because it not have this field. So it will not be added to select list.
nameMedia, idMedia and aboutMedia is not isJoinableField() but is isValidField(), so these 3 fields will be add at select list.
Now, alternativeTitle is isJoinableField(), so it will add nameAlternativeTitle in join alternativeTitle.
But when execute the query jpa throw folowing error:
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Cannot set field 'nameAlternativeTitle' to instantiate 'com.espacogeek.geek.models.MediaModel'
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:341) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14] 
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:160) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.impl.MediaRepositoryCustomImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.findMediaByNameOrAlternativeTitleAndMediaCategory(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]        
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:173) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:148) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]       
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:165) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at jdk.proxy7/jdk.proxy7.$Proxy260.findMediaByNameOrAlternativeTitleAndMediaCategory(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.espacogeek.geek.services.impl.MediaServiceImpl.findSerieByIdOrName(MediaServiceImpl.java:85) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:716) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at com.espacogeek.geek.services.impl.MediaServiceImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.findSerieByIdOrName(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.espacogeek.geek.controllers.MediaController.getSerie(MediaController.java:83) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:716) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at com.espacogeek.geek.controllers.MediaController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getSerie(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.InvocableHandlerMethodSupport.lambda$doInvoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethodSupport.java:113) ~[spring-graphql-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]    
        at io.micrometer.context.ContextSnapshot.lambda$wrap$1(ContextSnapshot.java:106) ~[context-propagation-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
        at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.InvocableHandlerMethodSupport.lambda$adaptCallable$1(InvocableHandlerMethodSupport.java:157) ~[spring-graphql-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPerTaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(ThreadPerTaskExecutor.java:314) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.InstantiationException: Cannot set field 'nameAlternativeTitle' to instantiate 'com.espacogeek.geek.models.MediaModel'
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl.injection(DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl.lambda$new$0(DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.beans.BeanInfoHelper.visitBeanInfo(BeanInfoHelper.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.beans.BeanInfoHelper.visitBeanInfo(BeanInfoHelper.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl.<init>(DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.assembler(DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.resolveAssembler(DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.createResultAssembler(DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.StandardJdbcValuesMapping.resolveAssemblers(StandardJdbcValuesMapping.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final] 
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper.createRowReader(ResultsHelper.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper.createRowReader(ResultsHelper.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final] 
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]    
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$2(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:382) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:418) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]    
        at jdk.proxy7/jdk.proxy7.$Proxy271.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.espacogeek.geek.repositories.impl.MediaRepositoryCustomImpl.findMediaByNameOrAlternativeTitleAndMediaCategory(MediaRepositoryCustomImpl.java:85) ~[classes/:na]  
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        ... 49 common frames omitted

Code:
    public List<MediaModel> findMediaByNameOrAlternativeTitleAndMediaCategory(
            String name,
            String alternativeTitle,
            Integer category,
            Map<String, List<String>> requestedFields) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<MediaModel> query = cb.createQuery(MediaModel.class);
        Root<MediaModel> mediaRoot = query.from(MediaModel.class);
        Join<MediaModel, AlternativeTitleModel> altTitlesJoin = mediaRoot.join("alternativeTitles", JoinType.LEFT);

        List<Selection<?>> select = new ArrayList<>();
        requestedFields.forEach((field, subFields) -> {
            try {
                if (Utils.isJoinableField(mediaRoot, field)) {
                    Join<Object, Object> join = mediaRoot.join(field, JoinType.LEFT);
                    join.alias(field);
                    subFields.forEach(subField -> {
                        if (Utils.isValidField(join.getModel().getBindableJavaType(), subField)) select.add(join.get(subField).alias(subField));
                    });
                } else if (Utils.isValidField(MediaModel.class, field)) {
                    select.add(mediaRoot.get(field).alias(field));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        query.distinct(true);
        query.multiselect(select);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (category != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(mediaRoot.get("mediaCategory").get("idMediaCategory"), category));
        }

        List<Predicate> namePredicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(mediaRoot.get("nameMedia"), "%" + name + "%"));
        }
        if (alternativeTitle != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(altTitlesJoin.get("nameAlternativeTitle"), "%" + alternativeTitle + "%"));
        }

        if (!namePredicates.isEmpty()) {
            Predicate orPredicate = cb.or(namePredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
            predicates.add(orPredicate);
        }

        if (!predicates.isEmpty()) {
            query.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
        }

        List<MediaModel> medias = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();

        return medias;
    }

What's should I do?
Update 11/11 - 20h04:
        List<Selection<?>> select = new ArrayList<>();
        requestedFields.forEach((field, subFields) -> {
            try {
                if (Utils.isJoinableField(mediaRoot, field)) {
                    Join<Object, Object> join = mediaRoot.join(field, JoinType.LEFT);
                    join.alias(field);
                    subFields.forEach(subField -> {
                        if (Utils.isValidField(join.getModel().getBindableJavaType(), subField)) select.add(join.get(subField).as(join.getModel().getBindableJavaType()).alias(subField));
                    });
                } else if (Utils.isValidField(MediaModel.class, field)) {
                    select.add(mediaRoot.get(field).alias(field));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        });

This way not throw any errors, but the object requested arrive null.
Update 11/11 - 20h50:
Follow the query generated:
    /* <criteria> */ select
        distinct mm1_0.id_media,
        mm1_0.about,
        mm1_0.name_media
    from
        medias mm1_0
    left join
        alternative_titles at1_0
            on mm1_0.id_media=at1_0.id_media
    left join
        alternative_titles at2_0
            on mm1_0.id_media=at2_0.id_media
    where
        mm1_0.id_category=?
        and mm1_0.name_media like ? escape ''
        and at1_0.name_title like ? escape ''

